# Swift How to implement and access Browser Information trough WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am trying to implement a payment service in my app, for which I need to be able to handle the "new" 3DS2 Secure Payment Process. This process requires me to load a URL returned by the service to complete the payment. I am having a few issues with implementing a WebView and feel like I am doing it the wrong way.

- For the process to work, I need to pass information about the Browser the user is using. To make this possible I am loading up a WKWebView with a URL that is just an empty page and want to get the information from there. However, I don't understand how to access that. The Info needed is the following:
  [image: Screenshot of the Info I need].
- After having collected all of that I call the API which then returns me an URL the user needs to be directed to. That's not a big issue.
- I also pass an URL to which the user is redirected after he has completed the process inside the webview. I need to be notified when the user gets to that page because I need to close the webview programmatically and can't think of another way to do this. I did not find any delegate methods that notify me when a new URL is loaded though.

I have read that UIWebView also exists but is older than WKWebView. I also need the browser to load just like a View, without the usual Browser UI (literally just the html & css).